# How to use ctypes transform uint8_t two-dimensional array to C program double pointer

Tags: python, c, ctypes

Now I have a C program function

```
uint8_t *join(uint8_t **shares, int secret_size, int k)
```

and I receive some binary data from socket.when i receive 24 bytes,
`data = connection.recv(24)`
I will use ***struct.unpack('BBB',data)*** as ***3 uint8_t interger***.

1. first, I want to transform ***3 uint8_t interger*** as a uint8_t array which length is equal to 3.
2. second,I want to use two uint8_t array as a `uint8_t **` to use C funcion.

but，I don't know to realize it with ctypes.Thanks

Comment: Unpacking `BBB` requires only 3 bytes, not 24.  Please clarify your question